# Why pyspark loads the first csv file longer than the rest?

Tags: python, csv, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When loading csv files with SparkSession the first job takes more time than the rest.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('example_app').master('local[*]').getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.csv('filename.csv', header=True)
```

File consist about 1M rows or 24MB, first load takes about 3 - 4 seconds, while the second load of the same file or different file of the same size takes only 140 - 200 ms.

I use local pyspark setup and tried to load file via jupyter notebook and terminal, results are the same.

[image: jupyter]

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

This won't explain the whole time differences but one of the reason is `import` will be cached.

Consider this example:

```
def myfunc(i):
    import pandas as pd
    
    return i * 100

myfunc(1) # 1.0467s
myfunc(1) # 0.00019s
```

When first time I call this function, it imports the `pandas` module and takes a loading time of the package. Second time it won't import and use the package from the cache which is faster.

Same thing is happening in `spark.read`.

Ex: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py#L70